# How to add spaces to text when using .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a combo of angularJS and jQuery working with the tooltip widget and a drop-down menu.

We're grabbing a bunch of names that come into a multi-select, and when I select several items from the drop down I'm pulling the text to get the labels (since the items are coming from a database, the value doesn't work, it just shows the numbers)

So right now I'm working with

```
$scope.selected = $('#filter option:selected').text();
```

If I select: 'red, blue, green' it's being displaced as redbluegreen.

Is there anyway I can keep the spaces using .text()? I've searched the site and can't find anything relevant.

Comment: fyi it is not advisable to mix jquery and angular in that way.

Comment: Yeah, I know... the entire site is kinda built in a weird hybrid of both. I know it's bad practice, but.... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.selected = $('#filter option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(' ');
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var selected = []; 
$('#filter :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
     selected.push($(selected).text()); 
});
```

Comment: you should use `.push`.

Comment: Yes, just realized. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery really has no business being used in a controller, here's a more appropriate angular solution that will update in real time using `ng-change`

HTML

```
<select multiple 
        ng-model="mySelect" 
        ng-options="opt.id as opt.val for opt in options" 
        ng-change="updateSelected()">
</select>
```

Controller

```
  var options = [
    {id: 1,val: 'item 1'}, 
    ..........
    {id: 6,val: 'item 6'}
  ];

  /* used in "ng-change" on select*/
  function updateSelected() {
    // map text from options
    $scope.selected = $scope.options.map(function(option) {
      return $scope.mySelect.indexOf(option.id) > -1 ? option.val : null
    }).join(' ');
  }

  // scope object
  var scope = {
    mySelect: [1, 3, 4], // ng-model for select
    selected : null,// space separated text variable
    updateSelected: updateSelected,
    options: options // options for select
  }
  // extend $scope with scope object
  angular.extend($scope, scope);
  // create initial options text
  $scope.updateSelected();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/QpOGVgWsq7iG1XNhTWCg?p=preview)**</kbd>